# How do I connect Studio3T IDE to MongoDB Atlas replica set (instead of a specific server in the replica set)?

Tags: mongodb, atlas, studio3t

Has anybody successfully connected the Studio3T IDE to a MongoDB Atlas replica set rather than to an individual member of the replica set?

Details:

When I try to use the "Replica Set" option in Studio3T to set up a connection to my Atlas replica set, I get the following error when I try to connect:

```
Connection failed.

Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@1398bb34. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[]
```

This error comes at the "Connecting to Server" step, after getting "OK" results returned from the "initializing the connection" step and "Configuring SSL" step.

I can connect directly to any one of the replica set servers without a problem, and I've added all three of those server addresses and ports to the list of members of the replica set in the connection dialog box. But when I try to have Studio3T choose how to connect to the replica set it fails with this error.

The bigger issue here is that I need to make sure that the connection goes to the primary server for writes and not the secondaries, but Atlas switches primary and secondary around pretty frequently, causing errors in my client code.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your connection string? What did you set in SSL/TLS settings?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - I'm not using a connection string, exactly, I'm trying to set it up from the dialog box that Studio3T provides. 

The connection string that works to set up an individual connection (not a replication set), with the password redacted will follow in the next comment.  When I try to follow the Studio3T docs to convert this to a replica set connection, everything works until it gets to the actual find a server step.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - Here's the connection string for a direct connection to one member of the replica set (password redacted):


mongodb://mdm_student:redacted_pwd@samplecluster-shard-00-02.78282.mongodb.net:27017/?ssl=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&authSource=admin&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&3t.uriVersion=3&3t.connection.name=Fall+23+Classes+server+-+mdm_student&3t.alwaysShowAuthDB=true&3t.alwaysShowDBFromUserRole=true&3t.sslTlsVersion=TLS

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - For SSL, "Use SSL to Connect" is checked, along with "Accept and certificate". It seems to get past the SSL setup step when trying to connect.

Comment: Please edit your question to put such additional information to it. In your Connection string I don't see the `replicaSet`. Did you check "Allow system certificates" (or similar)? Otherwise you must download the CA certificate from MongoDB homepage and put the file in the SSL connection dialog. Sorry, currently I have no access to my Studio 3T, thus I can help only based on my memory.